# Separate JSF and EJB apps

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb-3.0

How do I use a deployed EJB app from a separate JSF application?

I'm attempting to separate the two applications and access the EJB through the remote interface. To do this I have two eclipse projects - one contains the EJB and persistence logic, tested independently and works. I then created a JSF project that references the EJB project (so I gain access to the remote interface), however this fails when attempting to either inject the EJB instance or lookup the JNDI name (I've tried several variants to no avail). This is what my JSF backing bean contains:

@EJB(lookup="java:global/LocEJB/LocalityEJB!com.ame.business.LocalityEJBRemote")
private LocalityEJBRemote locality;

This is on Glassfish, and I am only referencing the EJB project and not packaging it with the JSF project. When I do the latter, I receive error initializing EJB container problems on the JSF project. So, how do I access the remote EJB and does the way I'm approaching this make any sense?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSF application has to know about the EJB interfaces (at least they did on EJB 2.0).  You're using the Proxy pattern to hide the fact that this is a remote component from your JSF client.

Comment: That's the essence of the question - how do I deploy the JSF so that I can compile against the interfaces and let the container manage the injection, but without requiring the EJBs and JSF to be packaged/deployed together?

Comment: You have to have the common code in both - that might be a JAR that they share.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can not use Local interface if trying to access outside the container. You must use Remote Interface.

You can define your Remote interface in the sun-web.xml or EJB injection in the bean.

sun-web.xml code:

```
<ejb-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>com.xxx.session.UserRemote</ejb-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>corbaname:iiop:127.0.0.xxx:3700#com.xxx.session.UserRemote</jndi-name>
  </ejb-ref>
```

Another thing you must have Remote interfaces in your classpath.